# Codeigniter index.php in the subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, subdirectory

I am new to Codeigniter. I want to make safe to the model, controller and views. I have found that it is good to put the index.php in a folder of public like below.
--root
  --application
  --public
      --css
      --js
      --assets
      --**index.php (the Codeigniter base index.php)**
      --**.htaccess**
  --system
**.htaccess**
What should I do for the file that bold,so that when I enter the "example.com/controller/method" can see my page. I don't want "example.com/index.php/controller/method" I hope you got the questions.

[edit]
I add more to explain.
I know how to hide index.php

**example.com/public/controller/method** => got the page
**example.com/controller/method** => can't got the page

I want the second one can show the page if I put the index.php into public folder!

Comment: It means Are you trying to remove `index.php` in your url ?

Comment: Then what do you mean by bold ?

Answer (score 0):

In the index.php you should change the `$system_path` and the `$application_folder` variables, and thats should do it.

In your case:

```
$system_path = '../system';
$application_folder = '../application';
```

And of course your document root must to point to your public folder.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve;

if you want to remove index.php from the url so you have

**example.com/controller/method** instead of **example.com/index.php/controller/method**

You need to create a .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, if you want to make it safer... I advised you to rename

`application` folder and `system` folder

E.g:

`application` change to `my_secret_application`

and

`system` change to `my_secret_system`

And in your `index.php`

```
$system_path = 'my_secret_application';
$application_folder = 'my_secret_system';
```